# How do I fix a 3DSmax MAXscript Auto load error?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I can't fix this problem during 3DS Max installation:

> `MAXscript` Auto load Error `"$startupScripts\\vraytutils.ms"`

[image]

Does anyone know how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 1):

For the current startup scripts folder use....

```
mypath = (GetDir #startupScripts + "vraytutils.ms")
```

or for the current User startup scripts folder use....

```
mypath = (GetDir #userStartupScripts + "vraytutils.ms")
```